# Transfer money between contracts

Tags: remix, contract-design, address.transfer, receive

I'm quite new at smart contracts/Solidity, which I'm learning for a postgraduate course.

In one of the assignments, we have to implement a little competitive game (something like the game of Seven Kingdoms). The main goal of puzzle is to be king and not be overthrow.

The contract of the SevenKingdoms

```
pragma solidity 0.5.0;

 contract SevenKingdoms {

  address payable public owner;
  address payable public king;
  uint public price;

  constructor(string memory _token) public payable {
    owner = msg.sender;
    king = msg.sender;
    price = msg.value;
  }

  function() external payable {
    require(msg.value > price);
    king.transfer(msg.value);
    king = msg.sender;
    price = msg.value;
  }
 }
```

From articles like [this](https://medium.com/better-programming/solidity-0-6-you-might-be-sending-ether-all-wrong-1e119e1ffc27), I understood that may be an issue when a contract is receiving money and doesn't implement receive method.

I decided to take advantage of this issue in order to be the king (address) of seven kingdoms, so I created the following contract.

King contact:

```
pragma solidity 0.6.1;

contract King {
    
    address payable public owner;
    uint public _price;

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    constructor () payable public {
        owner = msg.sender;
        _price = msg.value;
    }
    
    function triggerAddress(address payable _addr, uint256 valueInWei) public payable {
    _addr.transfer(valueInWei);  
   }
    
    receive() external payable {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Sorry I cannot receive money");
    }
}
```

Now when I am deploying the contracts in Remix and trying to transfer money(in Wei) from King to SevenKingdoms via its address (address contract for example 0x515df7f7cF195BFAA0f59bdD30B30f48B785aaFf) I am getting the following error message.

```
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
```

What I am doing wrong? Is there problem in the way how I use transfer method between contracts? How I can send money between contracts leveraging cotract's address ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in King's `triggerAddress` function. When it is used for transferring ether to SevenKingdoms' contract it will set the gas available to 2300.

```
function triggerAddress(address payable _addr, uint256 valueInWei) public payable {
    _addr.transfer(valueInWei);  
}
```

SevenKingdoms' fallback receives 2300 as gas stipend

```
function() external payable {
    require(msg.value > price);
    king.transfer(msg.value);
    king = msg.sender;
    price = msg.value;
}
```

Now when trying to transfer to previous the king it will run out of gas because a transfer cost 9000 gas.

A workaround is to use low-level call to make the transfer

```
function triggerAddress(address payable _addr, uint256 valueInWei) public payable {
    _addr.call.gas(gasleft()).value(valueInWei)("");  
}
```

Comment: Hello Ismael thank you for instant reply. In Javascript VM your solution works as expected but when I deploy the contracts to Ropsten Test Network and subsequently trigger "triggerAddress" function from King contract I get Out of gas. See transaction log https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x8e84127755d8023ce431981ad054ffc8ac519646f3315c5a5ed4803995c858dc

Comment: @nikosbob Did you try calling the function with more gas? You can check how much is used in remix and use that gas amount as base.